# How to OrderBy() 2 or more parameters?

Tags: c#

For example, I have an object with 3 properties: Name, Price and Description. I need to sort a collection of these objects. It's easy to sort by only one parameter:

```
var sortedList = ObjectCollection.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

But how to perform the sorting by 2 parameters (Name and Price). For example, I need to get a list like that:

```
ItemName1 $100 SomeDescription
ItemName1 $200 AnotherDescription
ItemName1 $250 AnotherDescription
ItemName2 $20 AnotherDescription
ItemName2 $40 Description
ItemName3 $100 Description
```

and so on. So, the main key is a Name, but if there are several items with the same name then the second key is the price. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sortedList = ObjectCollection.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ThenBy(x => x.SecondPropertyToOrderBy).ToList();
```

You can chain the OrderBy or OrderByDescending like this. I Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ThenBy` extension, as it does not override previously used `OrderBy` calls.

```
var sortedList = ObjectCollection.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ThenBy(x => x.Price).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`ThenBy()`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/baf47c50-24c2-4459-97fe-3912b979d32f/orderby-and-thenby?forum=linqprojectgeneral) using linq

```
ObjectCollection.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ThenBy(x => x.Price).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Enumerable.ThenBy`:

```
var sortedList = ObjectCollection.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ThenBy(x => x.Description).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq:

```
ObjectCollection.OrderBy(x => x.Name).
                 ThenBy(x => x.Price).ToList();
```

If you can't use Linq, you can write a [custom comparator](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727).